# Why isn't the cell's selection being recognized? Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

I need help with that. I'm trying to set a blurred view to appear when I click on a cell. I don't know if there is any function to detect if the cell is **touched** so I'm using the "selected" boolean value to check if it is selected/touched. After that, if there is an image in the image array I'd like to show it in the blurred view. A lot of apps to that, probably not like this but thats the only way I found. 
When I tested it, the selection is still appearing, but nothing is happening, like this code was never executed. If even the alert showed up I would know it is working, but it's not.

Observations: The cellImgView is a UIView I've added to put the image description, the image and a close button and the blur view mainly. All of those are set to hidden in the interface builder cause I just want to unhide them when a cell is touched.

**THIS CODE IS INSIDE THE FUNCTION:**

```
   tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Here is the code

```
if cell.selected == true { //!
            if let dataArr = dft.valueForKey("images") as? [NSData] {


                let nowImgData = dataArr[indexPath.row]
                let nowImg = UIImage(data: nowImgData)

                let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Dark)
                let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
                theCellView.addSubview(blurView)
                blurView.frame = theCellView.bounds

                theCellView.hidden = false
                theCellImgViewCloseBtn.hidden = false
                theCellImageDesc.hidden = false
                theCellImage.hidden = false

                theCellImage.image = nowImg
                theCellImageDesc.text = descriptions[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No image", message: "This cell has no image", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
```

Or even better, right click on your `UITableViewDelegate` inheritance and Jump To Definition to go through the available methods you have at your disposal. It's good to know what you have available to you.

Comment: @HenriqueDourado The function I provided is made for cell selections. It's NOT the same.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Let me try that and I'll give you a feedback. Thanks

Comment: Hm, it keeps saying "This code will never be executed"

Comment: @HenriqueDourado You're going to have to alter your code a bit. The selection will take care of the whole if statement. You can try simply printing something to the console to start when you tap a cell. If problems persist, update your code and I will help

Comment: Yeah its working now. Just the "else" statement that seems to not work, when there is no image with the cell it is crashing, I'll have a look at it. Thanks!